# Flask RESTful API and authenticating for a specific user

Tags: python, rest, flask, restful-authentication, flask-restful

I am relatively new to RESTful API, so it is certainly possible I am not designing this correctly.

I want to return a different subsets of a JSON user object from /api/users/[user_id] based on who is authenticating.  So if the user "alice" is trying to access /api/users/alice, she would get much more of her info (such as private settings, etc) than user "bob" who would simply get her public profile.

I am currently using flask_restful with httpbasicauth.  Right now I have the following:

```
class UserAPI(flask_restful.Resource):
    @g.auth.login_required
    def get(self, username):
        # here is where I want to get the HTTPBasicAuth username
        # to determine how much data to return

        user = User.objects(username=username).exclude('password').first()

        if user is not None:
            return user.to_json()
        else:
            flask_restful.abort(404, message='User not found: ' + username)
```

The issue is that I cannot seem to figure out a CLEAN way to get the HTTP basic auth data.  I know I could parse the request and decode the base-64 data, but I feel I shouldn't have to do that.  Or, even better, find a way to pass the user_id from /api/users/[user_id] into the login_required annotation.

I feel this is would be a very common use case so I can't figure out why I can't find anything in this area.  Am I designing this completely wrong?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest not using flask.ext.httpauth. I didn't find it very useful. I use a decorator that takes the Authorization header and checks it with the db. You can access the username entered in request.authorization.username and the password is in request.authorization.password.

```
from flask import request
from flask.ext.restful import abort, Resource
from functools import wraps

def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth:
            abort(401)
        user = User.objects(username=auth.username).first()
        auth_ok = False
        if user != None:
            auth_ok = verify_password(auth.password) == user.password
        if not auth_ok:
            return abort(401)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated


class UserAPI(Resource):
    @requires_auth
    def get(self):
        user = User.objects(username=request.authorization.username).\
            exclude('password').first()

        if user is not None:
            return user.to_json()
        else:
            abort(404, message='User not found: ' + username)
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  Didn't know about the request.authorization field :/